# Ninja Forms on WordPress - auto reset after submission?

Tags: forms, ninja-forms

I'm using Ninja Forms for enquiries as pop up on WordPress.

**The issue** after closing the form (click X in corner) - when re-opening the form it just shows the confirmation message - "thank you for submitting your form".

Is there an click-trigger (or anything else) that clears the form when the X is clicked to close the form - so that even if the form is opened immediately it's blank for another submission?

Many thanks!

Can't see any way to do this in form settings.